# Wake up from sleep mode

Tags: wakeup, sleep-mode

I have a beginner question,
when the device is in sleep mode, shoud I follow the Polling Readout Mode flowchart or the Interrupt readout Mode flowchart ?
[image: INTERRUPT mode FLOWCHART]

[image: POLLING readout mode FLOWCHART]

Comment: The question needs further expanding to be able to get a reasonable answer.  Which device is in sleep mode?  What / where are the flowcharts mentioned.  More detail, please.

Comment: I'am using a CO2 sensor ( USEQGSM1C82100, as a slave ) and a stm32L0 MCU ( As a master ),  I added the two files showing both flowcharts